# Why isn't my function working, i need to make a distance calculator

Tags: c, printf, function-call, conversion-specifier

Distance calculator, everything works until the program reaches the function, than the program just stops running. I tried removing the `void` and `int`s from the line I call the function in the main function but still nothing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


void distanceFunc(int x2, int x1, int y2, int y1, int distance);

int main ()
{
    int action = 0;
    int x1 = 0;
    int y1 = 0;
    int x2 = 0;
    int y2 = 0;
    int distance = 0;
    printf("Welcome to my calculator!\n");
    printf("1 - Calc distance between 2 points\n");
    printf("2 - Calc hypotenuse of triangle\n");
    printf("3 - Calc area and perimeter of circle\n");
    printf("4 - Calc area of rectangle\n");
    printf("5 - Calc are of square\n");
    printf("6 - Exit\n");
    scanf("%d", &action);
    if (action == 1)
    {
        printf("Enter point1 coordinates: ");
        scanf("%d %d", &x1, &y1);
        printf("Enter point2 coordinates: ");
        scanf("%d %d", &x2, &y2);
        void distanceFunc(int x2, int x1, int y2, int y1, int distance);
    }
    return 0;
}


void distanceFunc(int x2, int x1, int y2, int y1, int distance)
{
    distance = sqrt(pow(x2 - x1, 2) + pow(y2 - y1, 2));
    printf("Distance is %f\n", distance);
}
```

Comment: Does the code shown compile?

Comment: @alk yes it does, stops when reaching the function.

Comment: "*stops when*" so its doesn't completely compile, but ends issuing one or more errors and perhaps warnings as well., right?

Comment: No, it compiles but after entering the point coordinates it just ends.

Comment: In `printf("Distance is %f\n", distance);` you are passing `int` which does not satisfy `%f` specification.

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: Ok so i changed everything connected to  the distance variable to float but still same problem.

Comment: @alk gcc compiler

Comment: Thanks everybody, I figured it out.

Comment: Simplification: `sqrt(pow(x2 - x1, 2) + pow(y2 - y1, 2))` --> `hypot(x2-x1, y2 -y1)`

Answer (score 3):

In `main` you have

```
void distanceFunc(int x2, int x1, int y2, int y1, int distance);
```

This does not call the function, it only declares it (but you already did that at the top). You need

```
distanceFunc(x2, x1, y2, y1, distance);
```

You have a format mismatch too. You should change the type for `distance`.

```
double distance;
```

within the function, and remove the `int distance` function argument as it serves no purpose.

Answer (score 2):

```
    void distanceFunc(int x2, int x1, int y2, int y1, int distance);
```

is a function declaration, not a function call.

To call the function do just as you do for the other functions you use:

```
    distanceFunc(x2, x1, y2, y1, distance);
```

---

Also pump up the compiler's warning level by specifying the options:

```
-Wall -Wextra -pedantic
```

And see something like this:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:14:9: warning: unused variable ‘distance’ [-Wunused-variable]
     int distance = 0;
     ^
main.c: In function ‘distanceFunc’:
main.c:45:5: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("Distance is %f\n", distance);
     ^
main.c:45:5: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
```

and learn that `f` is not the correct conversion specifier to print an `int`.